# Due to my failing English?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I have a question. Here’s the sentence: I wasn’t accepted to college due to my failing English. 
Is “failing” here a gerund (meaning he failed English exam) or is it an adjective, describing his level of English?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! I guess it is nicer to show the effort you'd already made. For example, when I am not sure the usage of a word, I usually look up the definition/explanation and examples on a dictionary or other trusted reference. And then I might ask some question based on that. That would help answerers know what you've understood and what not. Here are some online free references that are commonly recognized,Wikipedia, Cambridge Dictionary, Oxford Dictionary, Collins Dictionary, VOA.

Answer (score 1):

> *I wasn’t accepted to college due to my failing English.*

It's ambiguous.

"My failing English" could be a clause functioning as complement of "to", or less likely it could be a noun phrase with the verb "failing" modifying "English".

Both alternants function as reason adjuncts, though with different meanings. As a clause it means that you weren't accepted because you failed the English course or exam. As a noun phrase it means that you weren't accepted because of your deteriorating English.

I'd say that the more salient interpretation is the clausal one.

Incidentally, in the noun phrase interpretation "failing" is not an adjective but a verb.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a gerund, but it depends on context. It is applicable in both senses — ‘his failing *of* an English exam’ or ‘his English getting worse’ — but if you used it as an adjective, it would imply that he *used* to have very good English, but now it has gotten much worse. However, the fact that he’s applying for college makes this usage unlikely; it’s difficult to attain the high level of English that is implied by the sentence *and then lose it again* by the time you’re thinking about tertiary education. Of course, older adults can apply for college too; it depends on context. If the person in question is young, it being used as an adjective is probably ruled out, and if it’s a general grammar question — like you might find on the same kind of English exam the person in question failed — it’s probably fairly safe to say that it’s used as a gerund.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It is common to say that a student whose grade in a subject is below the pass level has a 'failing grade' in that subject.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes, but people also say ‘due to my failing English’. There *are* generally other ways to express gerunds, but people still use them.

Comment: In a college admissions context, I would interpret 'failing' as indicating a grade, rather than a deterioration due to e.g. neurological causes.

Comment: I have met people who, you could say, had 'flailing English'.

Answer (score 0):

As written it is ambiguous.  As an adjective "failing" means "getting worse"

> I didn't get a driving licence due to my failing eyesight.

In that sentence it is certain that we mean that he is going blind, and "failing" is an adjective

On the other hand a gerund phrase, with the subject in the possessive form is also possible

> I didn't get a driving license due to my failing to perform an emergency stop.

That is clearly a gerund, since you can't modify "to perform an emergency stop"  with an adjective.  But the phrasing here is odd.

And, the phrasing of the original is also odd.  I assume it is a sentence that is designed to demonstrate ambiguity, since there are much easier ways to express the same:

> I wasn't accepted to college because I failed the English test.
>
> I wasn't accepted to college because my English is getting worse.